# Don't show password screen after using remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-10

I've just upgraded to Windows 10, I've disabled all the login screens by using the normal methods netplwiz and also disabling password after sleep. However whenever i remote desktop into my PC from an external source, After closing the remote desktop i have to then enter a password again to access my PC.

Is there a way to disable it so when i'm finished with the remote desktop it will just either auto login when i press enter or go back to windows screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable the logon screen. This is a mechanic of Remote Desktop.

So the question becomes, is it possible to somehow unlock it after it was locked?

It might. I haven't tested it, as personally I don't need this. If I need to take over my PC remotely, I use teamviewer. That way the pc won't be locked.

But lets assume RDP is the only method here.

There's a program called [logon.exe](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/51.htm) which allows you to unlock a computer using a username and password. For it to work, you need to set it to classic login as explained on that page.

Then, you can create a scheduled task that unlocks, where the trigger is an event called "Lock workstation".

So whenever the workstation is locked, task scheduler will unlock the workstation with your username and password. Of course, this does mean that you no longer will be able to lock your workstation.

Comment: I decided to just install a VNC Server and be done with remote desktop, Seems to work better for most things. thanks for your input anyway.